# Linux System Call Implementation - Linux Kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

I am trying to add a new system call that returns the total number of system calls made so far.  I can find the count of system calls by writing the below command in terminal.

```
cat /proc/kallsyms |grep _x64_sys |grep -v _eil* |wc -l
```

But I don't know how to implement this command in my new system call's C code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not clear to me why it needs to be a system call if it can be read from the `/proc` filesystem using file IO.

Comment: I would start with looking into how this particular file is implemented in kernel driver. This is not the real file, so if you look into code resposnbile for it, you will know how those stats are gathered. Once you've done that, you can than implement your own syscall doing the same.

Comment: The call table is arch-specific, but here is x86_64 https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.11.12/source/arch/x86/entry/syscall_64.c#L20

Comment: How can we obtain the system call number from the file you wrote?

Comment: I think you should modify kernel source code to implement new system call